# Cкрыть часть текста

Tags: javascript

Подскажите как можно скрыть часть текста с параграфами, вот так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: @Позитивонлайн, сделать блок фиксированной высоты и наложить сверху картинку, где прозрачность переходит в цвет границ блока.

Comment: @NickVolynkin, сомнительно, что кто-то будет утруждать себя поиском этой скрытой части текста на странице по ссылке. А вот скриншот в вопросе выглядит уже совсем по другому. Снял свой голос за закрытие вопроса. Комментарии можно удалять.

Answer (score 1):

jQuery:

```js
function more() {
    var p = $('p');
 p.toggleClass('open');
    if(p.hasClass('open')) {
        p.css('max-height', p.prop('scrollHeight'));
    } else {
        p.css('max-height', 38);
    }
}
```

```css
p {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    max-height: 38px;
    transition: 0.3s;
}

p:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    box-shadow: inset #fff 0 -30px 20px -15px;
    height: 30px;
}

p.open:after {
    height: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Doloribus voluptate eveniet ut asperiores libero ipsa, corrupti, rerum iste adipisci pariatur ipsum numquam dolore eius aut aliquid, nulla facilis odio dicta. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Doloribus voluptate eveniet ut asperiores libero ipsa, corrupti, rerum iste adipisci pariatur ipsum numquam dolore eius aut aliquid, nulla facilis odio dicta.
</p>
<button onclick="more();">Читать далее</button>
```

Чистый JS:

```js
function more() {
    var p = document.querySelector('p');
    p.classList.toggle('open');
    if(p.classList.contains('open')) {
        p.style.maxHeight = p.scrollHeight+'px';
    } else {
        p.style.maxHeight = '38px';
    }
}
```

```css
p {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    max-height: 38px;
    transition: 0.3s;
}

p:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    box-shadow: inset #fff 0 -30px 20px -15px;
    height: 30px;
}

p.open:after {
    height: 0;
}
```

```html
<p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Doloribus voluptate eveniet ut asperiores libero ipsa, corrupti, rerum iste adipisci pariatur ipsum numquam dolore eius aut aliquid, nulla facilis odio dicta. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Doloribus voluptate eveniet ut asperiores libero ipsa, corrupti, rerum iste adipisci pariatur ipsum numquam dolore eius aut aliquid, nulla facilis odio dicta.
</p>
<button onclick="more();">Читать далее</button>
```

Comment: А если внезапно текста будет больше, чем на `54px`?

Comment: @Deonis можно поставить `100vh` или динамически получать высоту через jQuery

Comment: При всем уважении... Вопрос не содержит метку [tag:jquery] - это предполагает либо ответ на чистом JavaScript, либо уточнение у автора в комменте (и добавление метки).